# Lightning Component UI switch back to old code

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Almost every day the LC I am building in a developer sandbox start showing the old version of the code. Then I have to wait 30 mins or so, for it to start reflecting the new code.

The LC is embedded in the lightning application, which is hosted on a VF page to work in Classic mode.

I have tried switching browser when this happens, but no luck. So seems like an SF side caching issue, and not my browser.

How can this be prevented? Thanks.

Comment: under session settings, there is a disable cache option

Comment: Have already disabled that, but no luck.

Comment: Did you try opening your browser in chrome incognito mode and  see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow this stopped happening a few days after I posted this question. Not sure what caused this issue, and what solved it later. Closing this ticket.